Proving uniform integrability of mean of iid L1 random variables, one definition of UI makes it easy, another makes it hard.
Overview of the question:
This question is about the proof of uniform integrability of $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i/n$, where the $X_i$ are iid $L^1$ functions. There are two definitions of uniform integrability, one definition makes it really easy to prove UI, another makes it really hard. Could you explain this, why does one definition make it easy, but another makes it really hard?
Some context:
There are two definitions of uniform integrability that are equivalent. I have asked about them in an earlier post here:
Equivalent definition for uniform integrability.
I will copy the definitions here:

Definition 1
A collection of random variables $X_i, i \in I$ is uniformly
integrable if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K$ such that
$$E[|X_i|\cdot1_{|X_i|\ge K}]\le \epsilon,$$ for all $i \in I$.
Definition 2
A collection of random variables $X_i, i \in I$ is uniformly
integrable, if there exists an $M$ such that
$$E[|X_i|]\le M,$$ for all $i \in I.$ And if for every $\epsilon>0$,
there exists a $\delta$ so that if $P(A)<\delta$, then  $$E[|X_i|\cdot
 1_A]\le \epsilon,$$ for all $i \in I.$

As is answered in another question by guy, the second definition makes it go through very quickly:
Does law of large numbers converge in $L^1$?
What I tried to do is prove that the $S_n$ is uniformly integrable using only the first definition, but the proof that the definitions are equivalent as an inspiration. I end up with this:
$$E[\lvert S_n \rvert \cdot 1_{\lvert S_n \rvert}\ge K]\le E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\lvert X_i\rvert}{n}\cdot 1_{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\lvert X_i\rvert}{n}\ge K}\right]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nE\left[\frac{\lvert X_i\rvert}{n}\cdot 1_{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\lvert X_i\rvert}{n}\ge K}\right].$$ Because of symmetry this is
$$E\left[\lvert X_1\rvert\cdot 1_{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\lvert X_i\rvert}{n}\ge K}\right].$$
However, even if the $X_i's$ are independent, it is not obvious that this expectation is bounded, or is it?
My quesitons:

Is there a direct way of showing that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $K$ such that the last expression is less than $\epsilon$ for all $n$? By Markvs inequality and identical distributions we can for a given $\epsilon>0$ bound $P(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\lvert X_i\rvert}{n}\ge K)$ for large enough $K$ and use the second definition of UI. But is there another way?

What is it actually that happens that when we create one definition that makes it much easier proving this? Do you see why when we create definition 2, the proof goes through very easy?, but when we have definition one it is much harder?



To answer your first question, it is general true that if $X \in L^1$ then for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever $\mathbb{P}(A) < \delta$ we have $$\mathbb{E}[X\cdot 1_A] < \varepsilon$$
(this is equivalent to showing the singleton family $\{X\}$ is UI as per the second definition but it is a fundamental result nonetheless). A quick way to show the above result is by contradiction: if not then there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ and a sequence $A_n$ of sets with $\mathbb{P}(A_n) < 1/n$ and $\mathbb{E}[X \cdot 1_{A_n}] \ge \varepsilon$, but this contradicts the Dominated Convergence Theorem.
Since you have found a way to bound $\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_n}{n} \ge K\right)$ the above result should allow you to conclude directly.
As to your second question: in this case I wouldn't say either definition works significantly better than the other, the core fact of both approaches is the above. Perhaps the method using the second definition is slightly cleaner since you avoid needing to bound the probabilities $\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_n}{n} \ge K\right)$ however.
